# How to count the number of tags that exist in Bootstrap Tags Input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-tags-input

I'm building a CMS and I'd like to have my Bootstrap Tags Input require a minimum of 6 tags as well as count the number of tags and display it on a counter, like this:

```html
<input type="text" data-role="tagsinput" placeholder="Add some tags!" id="tags" required>
<label for="tags">You must enter at least 6 tags. You have added <span id="tag-count">0</span> tags.</label>
```

`input#tags` will hold the tags, and the `span#tag-count` will display the number of tags.

How do I do this with JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: like that ? https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput

Answer (score 1):

if you ask about how count number of words in input text value you can convert it to array by spliting string by space skip empty elements(if you have more than one space beetwen words then its create empty element) and check length:

```js
const numOfWords = document.getElementById("tags").value
                  .split(" ").filter(word => !!word).length;
document.getElementById("tags-count").innerText = numOfWords;
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/), I'd say you can compute the count quite easily.

For instance using jQuery:

```
// both with return the count

$("#tags").val().split(",").length
// or
$("#tags").tagsinput('items').length
```

To update your count text, you can use:

```
$('#tags').on('itemAdded', function(event) {
  const count = $("#tags").val().split(",").length;
  $('#tag-count').text(count);
});
```